# popup is loaded after page loads, can't wire datepicker to textbox?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a page that loads, and then it loads the contents for a popup using ajax.

So the problem is, when I try and wire the .datepicker() to a textbox in the popup, it doesn't seem to work and I'm guessing it is a timing issue.

The .datepicker() wiring up occurs in the action/view that loads the contents of the popup.

So to summarize, the page loads, THEN it makes an ajax call to action/view to load the contents of the popup.  This popup has a textbox which should fireup a datepicker when clicked.

It isn't working, is this a timing issue?

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any issue with putting the call to `.datepicker()` in the Ajax success function, after the point at which the textbox is added to the DOM. If that's not working then I don't think it's a timing issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to **bind** your datepicker() method on ajax-call

Answer (score 0):

Might have something to do with the fact that some jQuery-ui functions don't work on hidden elements? eg, you've loaded the ajax, then  bind it, and only then it gets displayed? (the input bot that is)